# Collections and object initializers in C#

Tags: c#

I need to store reference to a parent object in hierarchical dataset shown below.
Is it even possible using an object initializer? Is there any keyword which refers to 'parent' initializer or do I have to do this the classic way - declare the parent object first?

(I have no idea what to write in between '?' characters)

```
Scenarios.Add(new Scenario()
{
    scenarioNumber = Scenarios.Count,
    scenarioDescription = "Example scenario",
    Steps = new BindingList<Step>()
    {
        new Step(){ parent = ?Scenario?, stepNumber = 1, subSteps = new BindingList<Step>() },
        new Step(){ parent = ?Scenario?, stepNumber = 2, subSteps = new BindingList<Step>() },
        new Step(){ parent = ?Scenario?, stepNumber = 3,
            subSteps = new BindingList<Step>()
            {
                new Step() { parent = ?Step?, stepNumber = 1, subSteps = new BindingList<Step>() },
                new Step() { parent = ?Step?, stepNumber = 2, subSteps = new BindingList<Step>() },
            },
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object initializer construct does not allow this.

You can use a static factory method instead, for example:

```
static Scenario Create(int scenarioNumber, string scenarioDescription, BindingList<Step> steps)
{
    var scenario = new Scenario()
    {
        scenarioNumber = scenarioNumber,
        scenarioDescription = scenarioDescription,
    };
    foreach (var step in steps)
    {
        step.parent = scenario;
    }
    scenario.Steps = steps;
    return scenario;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible.

You will have to declare variables to hold the parent objects and add them manually, one at a time. The initializer syntax cannot help you here.

Comment: You can still use list initializer after scenario is created : `scenario.Steps = new BindingList() {new Step(), new Step()} ;` The only exception to that is for the subSteps

Answer (score 0):

For me it will not be possible to avoid parent creation and then affecting it : as far as I know, object initializer is doing its work as if it were inside the constructor, so your parent `Scenario` instance is not yet created when you initialize its inside collection

And sorry if I'm mistaken